# How do I change a listening rule with netcat?

Tags: linux, networking, netcat

I have a server that has a rule like so when I check `netstat -tulpn`:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

This has been all well and good as the mysql database we've use has only needed local access, but now I want to remote connect to it too.  I need my `netstat -tulpn` to read like so:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

How do I update this?  I've been looking through `nc` but everything seems to only talk about setting up listening for the first time.  Whenever I try to assign a new rule I get a message like this:

```
(base) ct@do-not-touch:/$ sudo nc -l 0.0.0.0 3306   
nc: Address already in use
```

How do update the `127.0.0.1:3306` rule to be for `0.0.0.0:3306`?  Am I somehow totally off base here?

Comment: Did you stop the existing server process before you tried to start the new one?

Comment: Hmm... I don't think I did... so mysql is using 3306 locally, I have to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't* have two processes listening on the same IP and port. Since 0.0.0.0 means listen on all IPs, you can't bind to it if there's anything bound to any IP on that port. Stop the existing process listening on 127.0.0.1:3306, and then you'll be able to start one listening on 0.0.0.0:3306.

*: Technically, a flag called `SO_REUSEPORT` does exist, and forking after binding lets you do it as well, but neither is useful in your situation.

Comment: So how do I do that process

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if you run into this in the future, you have kill the process that is using whatever port but first you must know that port.

`sudo lsof -t -i:3306`

Then `kill` whatever id.